# Trying to make an function call to an external file with PhP, MySQL using WAMP

Tags: php, mysql, windows, wamp

I'm sure there is a simple answer to this, but I have been fumbling with everything for almost a week now and surrender. I am trying to build a shopping cart app and every coding solution I build will work when I include the code on the same page, but when I try to use an external page to run the function it does not seem to return the data. I have tried various monitoring techniques to determine what it is happening.

Here is the code for the main page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <title>Cart Connection</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    </head>

    <body>
            <p>Will this display?</p>
            <p><a href='<?php echo "showCart.php?PHPSESSID=" . session_id() ?>'>View Cart</a></p>

            <?php
                $Database = "L3TtL2B5DdY";
                $Table = "tblProds";

                if (isset($_SESSION['curCart']))
                    $Cart = unserialize($_SESSION['curCart']);
                else
                {
                    if (class_exists("shoppingCart"))
                    {
                        $Cart = new shoppingCart();
                        $Cart->setDatabase($Database);
                        echo ("<p>If statement ran successfully</p>");
                    }
                    else
                        exit("<p>The shoppingCart class is not available!");
                }


                $Cart->setTable($Table);
                $Cart->getProductList();
                $_SESSION['curCart'] = serialize($Cart);
            ?>
            <p><a href='<?php echo "showCart.php?PHPSESSID=" . session_id() ?>'>View Cart</a></p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the relevant code on the "shoppingCart.php" page:

```
<?php
    class shoppingCart
    {
        private $dbConn = "";
        private $dbName = "";
        private $tableName = "";
        private $orders = array();
        private $orderTable = array();

        function _construct()
        {
            $this->dbConn = @new mysqli("localhost", "root", "");
                if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
                    die("<p>Unable to connect to the database server.</p>" . "<p>Error Code " . 
                    mysqli_connect_errno() . ": " . mysqli_connect_error() . "</p>");
        }

        public function setDatabase($Database)
        {
            $this->dbName = $Database;
            @$this->dbConn->select_db($this->dbName)
                Or die("<p>Unable to select the database.</p>" . "<p>Error code " . mysqli_errno($this->dbConn) . 
                ": " . mysqli_error($this->dbConn) . "</p>");
        }

        public function setTable($Table)
        {
            $this->tableName = $Table;
        }

        public function getProductList()
        {
            $sqlString = "SELECT prodID, prodName, prodPrice FROM $this->tableName";
            @$qryResult = $this->dbConn->query($sqlString)
                Or die("<p>Unable to perform the query.</p>" . "<p>Error code " . mysqli_errno($this->dbConn) . 
                ": " . mysqli_error($this->dbConn) . "</p>");
            echo "<table width='100%' border='1'>";
            echo "<tr><th>Product ID</th><th>Product Name</th><th>Product Price</th><th>Select Item</th></tr>";
            $row = $qryResult->fetch_row();
            do
            {
                echo "<tr><td>{$row[0]}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$row[1]}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$row[2]}</td>";
                echo "<td><a href='showCart.php?PHPSESSID=" . session_id() . "&operation=addItem&productID=" . $row[0] . 

"'>Add</a></td></tr>";
                $row = $qryResult->fetch_row();
            } while ($row);
            echo "</table>";
        }

......
?>
```

When I try to load the main page it will display the two

lines and that is all. I debugged all the errors when I first created the code and thought it would work. When I wrote the original version of this page I put the "connection" code on the same page and the table displayed fine, so I don't know what else it could be.
I installed WAMP on my Windows XP box and it seems to work fine. I haven't touched the configuration files for any of the programs and all my other test code seems to work fine. It is just when I try to contact an external file.
Any help would be greatly appreciated as I think my brain is turning to mush.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to include the ShoppingCart.php file in your main page, so it has the definition of the ShoppingCart class. Try putting at the top of your main page:

```
<?php require('ShoppingCart.php'); ?>
```

What I think might be happening is that the cart object is getting unserialised from the Session, but there is no class definition, so it becomes an instance of an incomplete class. When you then call a method on it you are getting a fatal error. What probably doesn't help is that you may not be displaying errors, so the script will just end. You could also try putting at the top of the main page:

```
<?php ini_set('display_errors', true); ?>
```

This should make PHP errors get shown.

**Edit**

It might be worth pointing out that you can't store a database connection in the session. You need to connect to the server / select the database etc. on every request. I don't think your script is currently doing that.

Also, you can store objects in the session without worrying about the serialisation yourself, here is a quick example:

```
<?php
//include class definition before starting session.
require('ShoppingCart.php');

session_start();

if (!isset($session['cart'])) {
    $session['cart'] = new ShoppingCart();
}

$cart = $session['cart'];

//do stuff to cart
$cart->doSomething();

//changes are now saved back to the session when the script is terminated, without you having to do anything.
```

Comment: Good call on the deserialization.

Comment: OOPS I thought I copied the entire code from the main page. I do have the require code added. This is what I have before the code I already posted:
<?php
 require_once("shoppingCart.php");
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['curCart'];
?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict-dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

 <head>
  <title>Cart Connection</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
 </head>
...

Answer (score 0):

You need to

```
include_once("ShoppingCart.php");
```

Read up on the different ways to include files

http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_includes.asp